# OpenGL spectrum between perspective and orthogonal projection

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, projection, perspective, orthogonal

In OpenGL (all versions, though I happen to be working in OpenGL ES 2.0) there is the option of using a perspective projection versus an orthogonal one. Is there a way to control the degree of orthogonality?

For the sake of picturing the issue (and please don't take this as the actual question, I am well aware there is no camera in OpenGL) assume that a scene is rendered with the viewport "looking" down the -z axis. Two parallel lines extending a finite distance down the -z axis at (x,y)=1,1 and (x,y)=-1,1 will appear as points in orthogonal projection, or as two lines that eventually converge to a single pixel in perspective projection. Is there a way to have the x- and y- values represented by the outer edges of the screen remain the same as in projection space - I assume this requires not changing the frustum - but have the lines only converge part of the way to a single pixel?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to control the degree of orthogonality?

Either something *is* orthogonal, or it is not. There's no such thing like "just a little orthogonal".

Anyway, from a mathematical point of view, a perspective projection with an infinitely narrow field of view is orthogonal. So you can use glFrustum with a very large near and far plane distance, together with a countering translation in modelview to bring the far away viewing volume back to the origin.